# Problema de CORS ao fazer chamada GET no Angular 6

Tags: angular, http, cors

Quando eu chamo a seguinte URL: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxk616n8wjgGeHZIc3Hm66Kcv4ZtWKZJQnEKLsxZC9LpoDK8mQZ/exec diretamente no browser ou no POSTMAN eu recebo o JSON corretamente, mas quando eu tento chamar o mesmo link via GET no Angular, eu recebo o erro: "Failed to load https://script.googleusercontent.com/macros/echo…: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access."

Estou usando um HttpClient normal:

```
getTabela() {
  return this.http.get<TabelaEstatistica[]>('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxk616n8wjgGeHZIc3Hm66Kcv4ZtWKZJQnEKLsxZC9LpoDK8mQZ/exec');
}
```

Alguém sabe o que eu devo fazer para receber o JSON na minha aplicação?

Comment: Problemas de cors devem ser resolvidos no backend.

Comment: Sim é que o backend nesse caso é um webservice da google.

Comment: vc pode criar um serviço de proxy que chama este serviço e repassa os dados pra sua aplicacao. Ou ver alguma configuração nesse serviço do google.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui descobrir o problema. A minha aplicação Angular possui uma classe interceptor que pega todas as minhas requisições HTTP e insere um JWT, pois tenho uma aplicação Spring no backend que espera isso em todas as requisições.

Todavia, essa requisição GET que estou fazendo não é para o meu backend, mas sim para um webservice externo. Quando eu mando esse JWT na requisição GET ao endpoint da google, eles reclamam e dá esse problema de CORS.

Eu teria então duas soluções:

1) Em vez de fazer essa requisição GET direto do minha aplicação Angular, fazer pelo backend, tratar o dado e aí sim, entregar para o angular.

2) Evitar que aquela chamada HTTP em específico passasse pelo meu interceptor. Foi a solução que utilizei por ser mais rápida para mim, utilizando o HttpBackend, desta forma a requisição não vai passar pelo interceptor:

```
 private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(handler: HttpBackend) {
    this.http = new HttpClient(handler);
   }

  linkTabela = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxk616n8wjgGeHZIc3Hm66Kcv4ZtWKZJQnEKLsxZC9LpoDK8mQZ/exec';

    getTabela() {
      return this.http.get<TabelaEstatistica>(this.linkTabela);
    }
```

Comment: voce tem uma aplicação angular no backend?

Comment: desculpe, escrevi errado. já corrigi